# [Spark]: Using compiled jar copy of Spark in Jupyter

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I built a jar copy of Spark from https://github.com/apache/spark.git with some code modifications.

To call this jar into jupyter with Spark 1.5.1 (Scala 2.10) kernel, i used the %AddJar magic which looks like this:

```
%AddJar file:/Directory/To/filename.jar
```

My problem now is that whenever I try to call

```
import org.apache.spark.mllib.recommendation.ALS
```

the kernel calls the default implementation inside the kernel. Is there a way to call what's on my jar file instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I came up with is this,

1. Use the same version of Spark as the one in the Spark kernel (In my case, Spark 1.5.1) so that the new jar file is compatible with the kernel.
2. Find the location of the particular edited jar file and replace it with the modified code. (In my case, I edited the mllib module so I had to find the mllib jar file and replace with the new one.)

Tip: Keep the original jar file in case the new code breaks.